# C# Winforms - MessageBox from a worker thread - alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface, compact-framework

I have a worker thread doing some stuff that may sometimes discover that it requires some immediate user input before it can complete.

At the moment I'm considering Invoking a `MessageBox` on the UI thread, making the worker wait for the `DialogResult` from that, then continuing...but this is a fairly horrific UI design choice (the user may be in the middle of typing or clicking when the `MessageBox` pops up and may accidentally pick an option without even seeing it).

Can someone recommend a better way of approaching this?

Whatever it is needs to be very small and lightweight (I'm using the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 and the device it's being used on has a tiny screen).

Thanks

Comment: One alternative would be to show a notification somewhere in the UI that the user can choose to activate when he's ready. And when needed, force the user to handle these "pending choices" before shutdown.

Comment: It looks like you're facing two completely different problems. The first is passing control to the UI and getting back the response - you're effectively solving this one by invoking MessageBox on the UI thread etc. The second is having a good UX in this case and I am pretty sure this is not related to C#, .Net etc and greatly depends on the way you handle UI in your application and on your device in general.